# CSS :after used to make arrow for links not working for submit button

Tags: css, forms

Ive used the CSS :after selector to create an arrow for my links. This works fine but now I want to do the same thing to form inputs.

If I use the same class on the submit button then the :after is ignored, im assuming because the element cant contain other other elements.

If I apply the class to a div containing the submit button then it looks fine, but the arrow and padding outside of the actual submit button isnt clickable.

Is there a solution to this?

http://jsfiddle.net/jn7Vj/5/

```
.button-style {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #02AD85, #019975);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #02AD85, #019975);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #02AD85, #019975);
    padding: 0.7em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #003E30;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0px #252D42;
    font-size: 15px; //findme
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px; //findme
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.button-style:after {
       content: '';
       display: inline-block;
          width: 0px;
       height: 0px;
       border-style: solid;
       border-width: 0.4em 0 0.4em 0.7em;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
      margin-left: 0.75em;
    }

.button-style input {
       background: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


<a href="#" class="button-style">Here is a link</a>

<form class="webform-client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cchetwood/4/contact" method="post" id="webform-client-form-4" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-full-name">

<input type="text" id="edit-submitted-preferred-times-to-contact-optional" name="submitted[preferred_times_to_contact_optional]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">

<input type="submit" class="button-style" value="Submit">

<div class="button-style">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">   
</div>


</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS `after` pseudo element doesn't work on input fields (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840768/css-after-input-does-not-seem-to-work). Unfortunately your only solution here is to add the triangle as a background image on the input field or surround the field with something like a `div` or a `span` and add the `after` selector to that element.

As for your button, I would suggest changing it from an input element to a `button`, you can then apply the `after` selector to that.

**EDIT**
After reading your question again, I'm not sure if you want to add the triangle to your text input but here is a jsFiddle with the style added only to the buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/jn7Vj/9/

Answer (score 0):

1. add for .button-style `position:relative; padding: 0;`
2. add for .button-style input `padding: 0.7em 2em 0.7em 1em;` --> you can change this sizes, main idea is move padding from .button-style to .button-style input
3. add next css-rules for .button-style:after

`position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:10%;
    margin: -0.2em 0 0 0;`